# update all ng-repeat input values

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

It has been more than two weeks that I have been trying to solve my problem, but in vain and I really need your help please...
In the code, there's ng-repeat, and I have to update "frais" of all values displayed by ng-repeat. how can I do that please, I m working with angularJS and PHP

file.html

```
<ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="FactureAdminCtrl">

<ion-list ng-repeat = "selectedName in selected">
      <div class="item item-divider center-text" 
           name="codeE" ng-model="selectedName.CodeEnvoiColis"> 
        {{selectedName.CodeEnvoiColis}}
      </div>  

      <label class="item item-input">
      <input width="20%" type="text" 
          placeholder="Frais" ng-model="selectedName.FraisFact" 
          style="color:#BA1B1B;">
      </div> 
      </label>

</ion-list>  

    <a class="button button-info" href="#/factureAdmin" `
          ng-click=updateFact(selectedName)> Submit </a>
```

app.js

```
$scope.updateFact = function(selectedName){ 

   $http.post(  
        "http://localhost/deb/updatFact.php",  
        { 

        'FraisFact':$scope.selectedName.FraisFact,
        'CodeEnvoiColis':$scope.selectedName.CodeEnvoiColis,
      }
   ).success(function(data){  
        alert(data);                                
   });  

}
```

updateFact.php

```
 <?php   

      $CodeEnvoiColis = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->CodeEnvoiColis);  
      $FraisFact = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->FraisFact);  

      $query = "UPDATE colis SET FraisFact='$FraisFact' WHERE CodeEnvoiColis='$CodeEnvoiColis'" ;

 ?>
```

How can I do please!

Comment: Are you wanting to update each "Frais" individually or all of them at once?

Comment: all of them at once, because I have one button submit , wish you can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the same PHP function try the following:

Change the submit ng-click function to updateAll();

app.js

```
$scope.updateAll = function(){ 

  // create an array of promises with request to save every single name
  var promises = $scope.selected.map(function(name) {
    return $http.post("http://localhost/deb/updatFact.php", { 
        'FraisFact':name.FraisFact,
        'CodeEnvoiColis':name.CodeEnvoiColis,
      })
  });

  // execute them all
  $q.all(promises).then(function() {
    console.log('All names are saved');
  });

}
```

Comment: WOW , it reaaly solves my problem, I wasted a lot of time trying to solve it, I don't know how to thank you , thank you ,thank you very very very much

Comment: There is a small problem of the fact that with the same button I have to insert other data (input) in another table, the problem is that the insertion of its values is done several times, how can I distinguish These values of others please